# Request always pulls a 404 (python)

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

So, I'm tryin python and ive come to a strange poblem. Im trying to see if a YT video id is valid,
This part; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**QB7ACr7pUuE** and it always prints 404 even with a valid url.

Code:

```
import requests

def check_video_url(video_id):
    checker_url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
    video_url = checker_url + video_id

    request = requests.get(video_url)
    return request.status_code == 200
```

and

```
testId = "QB7ACr7pUuE"

check_video_url(video_id=testId)
print(str(status))
```

I'm not getting any errors. any ideas?

Comment: You code **should** raise an error as `status` is NEVER defined. Your code, like this may raise an error

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you don't check the returned value from `check_video_url`:

```py
import requests


def check_video_url(video_id):
    checker_url = (
        "https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
    )
    video_url = checker_url + video_id

    request = requests.get(video_url)
    return request.status_code == 200


testId = "QB7ACr7pUuE"
print(check_video_url(video_id=testId))  # <-- Here I print the returned value
```

Prints:

```
True
```

---

```py
testId = "QB7ACr7pUuExxx"   # <--- non-existent video ID
print(check_video_url(video_id=testId))
```

Prints:

```
False
```

---

EDIT: To put the returned value to variable:

```py
testId = "QB7ACr7pUuExxx"
status = check_video_url(video_id=testId)

if status:
    print("Valid ID")
else:
    print("Invalid ID")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! would there be a way to put that in a variable?
if so, how would I assign it?
```
if var == true:
    print("Valid!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding upon @Andrej's answer. I would suggest that you use
**request.ok** and return your message

> ok - Returns True if status_code is less than 400, otherwise False

```
import requests

def check_video_url(video_id):
    checker_url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
    video_url = checker_url + video_id

    request = requests.get(video_url)
    return request.ok

testId = "QB7ACr7pUuE"

status = check_video_url(video_id=testId)
if status:  
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Not Valid")
```

Comment: Never return True/False based on a boolean condition, return the condition directly as `return request.ok`

Comment: @azro Agreed, My mistake. I wanted to return string "Valid" or "Not Valid" based on boolean condition. I have edited same. please check now

Comment: Hum better to return a boolean then let the caller to decide what to do with it, but that's your answer, as you want

Comment: Makes sense. Let me make that change. Thanks for the suggestion